# QGIS 3.0 (from OSGeo4W Installer) unusable on HiRes Displays?

Tags: gui, qgis-3

Just installed QGIS 3.0 from OSGeo4W Network installer on a 13'' convertible notebook with 3200x1800 resolution (Win10) and it looks like this (toolbars and menu bar cover nearly half the display height, default icon size 24, default font size 8pt):

[image]

It is absolutely unusable, and I wonder why the 2.99.0-301 (installed exactly the same way) from last week looked totally normal.

Do I miss something?

cp. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short answer, but an answer. Perhaps it should be - at least on windows - good practice to reboot the machine after installing some software.

Having done so, I can just state that this issue is now solved, and my QGIS 3.0 looks absolutely normal:

[image]

Comment: Can you accept your own answer please?

Comment: As soon as the system let's me...